# Javascript convert string from utf-8 to iso-8859-1

Tags: javascript, jquery, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I know this sounds bad, but it's necessary.

I have a HTML form on a site with utf-8 charset which is sent to a server which works with the iso-8859-1 charset. The problem is that the server doesn't understand correctly characters we use in Spain like `à, á, è, é, ì, í, ò, ó, ù, ú, ñ, ç` and so on. So if I search something like `artículo` it answers nothing found with `artÃ­culo`.

I send the form with ajaxform (http://malsup.com/jquery/form/), and the code loks like this:

```
$(".form-wrap, #pagina").on("submit", "form", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).ajaxSubmit({

        success: function(data){
            $("#temp").html(data);
            //Handle data in #temp div
            $("#temp").html('');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

My problem is: I have no acces to the search server and I cannot change the whole website to iso-8859-1 encodig since this would break other stuff.

I have alredy tried with no succes these scripts:

- http://phpjs.org/functions/utf8_decode/
- http://phpjs.org/functions/utf8_encode/
- http://ecmanaut.blogspot.com.es/2006/07/encoding-decoding-utf8-in-javascript.html

May I be doing everything wrong?

**Edit:** the `escape` function isn't useful for me as it turns these spacial chars into `%` prefixed codes which are useless to the server, it then searches for `art%EDculo`.

**Edit** using the `encodeURIComponent` function the server understands `art%C3%ADculo`. P.S. I just use the word `artículo` for testing but the solution it should cover all special chars.

Comment: Try good old [`escape`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape) to encode your strings. Better yet, find the one who runs that server and [hit them with a chicken](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y3ln6mp0HNM)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I transcode a Javascript string to ISO-8859-1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283829/how-do-i-transcode-a-javascript-string-to-iso-8859-1)

Comment: @georg Yes i would hit him with a chicken (but a living one) if I could, escape isn't useful as it leaves the char code prefixed with an `%`. @matthew-herbst I'm not sure if it really is a duplicate, I have alredy tried the answers from that question but it doesn't help.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Finally the one who runs that server gave us access to the server and we made an utf-8 compatible php script. So I don't care any more.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a HTML form on a site with utf-8 charset which is sent to a server which works with the iso-8859-1 charset.

You can try setting form [accept-charset](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_accept_charset.asp):

```
<form accept-charset="iso-8859-1">
....
</form>
```

Comment: I Also tied this, it seems the browser just ignores it and sends utf-8.

Comment: @Falk: Sounds more like your `ajaxSubmit` plugin ignores it, not the browser.

Comment: It could be, I'll think about it. Anyway the problem is solved, finally we got access to the server.

Comment: I had the same situation with utf8 on client and iso8859-1 on server and this fixed my issue